# How to define shared sequence generator in Hibernate / JPA?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

We import data to DB by external process and also allow to modify/add data inside app. To avoid UUIDs and simplify code single Oracle DB sequence `HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE` is used in external process and I need to use it for affected entities.

My naive definitions on each entity are failed:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE")
```

with:

> HibernateException: Multiple references to database sequence [hibernate_sequence] were encountered attempting toset conflicting values for 'increment size'.

Defining only on singe entity:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE")
```

(and `@GeneratedValue` on others) causes:

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown Id.generator: HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE

How I can use single sequence on different entities?

**UPDATE** Also I had:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Multiple references to database sequence [hibernate_sequence] were encountered attempting toset conflicting values for 'increment size'.  Found [1] and [50]

at some stage as previously I defined physical sequence as:

```
create sequence HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE
minvalue 1
maxvalue 9999999999999999999999999999
start with 1
increment by 1;
```

and default hibernate step is 50...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like stupid solution of using separate Hibernate logical names works:

```
@Entity
public class Cat {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Cat_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "Cat_seq", sequenceName = "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1)
    Long id;
}

@Entity
public class Dog {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Dog_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "Dog_seq", sequenceName = "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1)
    Long id;
}
```

`SequenceGenerator.sequenceName` set physical sequence name which should correctly work as Hibernate can't make ay assumption on exclusive use of physical object in distributed environment which Oracle DB is...

`allocationSize = 1` should be provided as default value is 50 which is different fro original physical sequence definition.